# Polymer, how to select element that is inside conditional template

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Here is the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/x2zotqDhkNuwHaEI6oJO?p=preview) with described problem:

**How to select the 'model-el' that is inside conditional template:**

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{employees}}" id="model_template">
    <model-el 
      id="model"
      employees="{{employees}}"
    >second-child calling</model-el>  
</template>
```

{{employees}} data is seated in 'attached' callback. Selecting is attempted in separate on-click call.

Goal is to access 'model-el.test()' function in the on-click event:

```
model-el.test();
```

I have tried differed ways, as:

```
      //var model_el = this.$.model;
      //var model_el = document.querySelector('model');
      //var model_el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('model');

      console.log(model_el);
      //Goal
      model_el.test();
```

Comment: Not sure if you made a typo, but what would `if="{{employees}}"` accomplish? If what?

Comment: means that employees data is there, it's is initiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.$....` only supports elements which are statically added.
For your use case use `var model_el = this.$$('#model');`. This is the short form of `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#model')`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! My bad for not looking at the right place first, docs: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding

Comment: Don't worry. I guess this is the most frequently asked Polymer question of all time. AFAIR there is an open Polymer issue to make this information more prominent.